# Populate "Lab" Domain via LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have a lab environment where I need to own Active Directory Services/DNS/DHCP/etc at work. I have a pseudo "production" environment in this lab that has everything from vCenters to Jenkins to VDI testing. Using this "Lab" domain, I can create users and everything works as expected.

The current challenge I'm running into is this test environment is becoming more useful to the team(s) and user maintenance is just starting to get cumbersome.  The company has a primary domain "main" that everyone uses outside this test environment. Many of our traditional tools have LDAP binds into the "main" domain so credentials are handled via company IT.

I'm looking for pointers on how to accomplish something like an LDAP bind to the "main" domain that populates the "lab" domain WITHOUT trusts. No trusts are allowed (understandably). I just want to make my servers forward to the "lab" domain (lab\user1) which strips "lab" and does a credential check against "main" instead (main\user1).

I can easily adjust the manner in which I have the environment set up if there are alternative tools that give us the control to add items to the domain/handle internal permissions but passes all authentication upstream via an LDAP bind.

P.S. Pardon any confusion of terms...software developer just getting his feet wet in this space.

Comment: `I'm looking for pointers on how to accomplish something like an LDAP bind to the "main" domain that populates the "lab" domain WITHOUT trusts` - Populates the lab with what? `I just want to make my servers forward to the "lab" domain (lab\user1) which strips "lab" and does a credential check against "main" instead (main\user1)` - Forwards what?

Comment: Credentials. So if I could pull the "main" users in the "lab" domaim as needed and forward authorization checks to "main". So password management is handled on that side instead of in lab.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a way to set up **referrals** from your test LDAP server to your main domain.

<s>The specific way to configure that depend on what LDAP server you're using.</s>

Take a look at this to have an idea about what referrals are http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch7/referrals.html

Edit: you're talking about AD. Then read this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978014.aspx